# Combine multiple columns into one category column using the column names as value label

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data

```
   ID      A      B      C
0   0   True  False  False
1   1  False   True  False
2   2  False  False   True
```

And want to transform it into

```
   ID group
0   0     A
1   1     B
2   2     C
```

- I want to use the column names as value labels for the `category` column.
- There is a maximum of only one `True` value per row.

This is the MWE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': range(3),
    'A': [True, False, False],
    'B': [False, True, False],
    'C': [False, False, True]
})

result = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': range(3),
    'group': ['A', 'B', 'C']
})
result.group = result.group.astype('category')

print(df)
print(result)
```

I could do `df.apply(lambda row: ...magic.., axis=1)`. But isn't there a more elegant way with pandas' own tools?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use melt then a lookup based on the column where the values are true to get the results you are expecting

```
df = df.melt(id_vars = 'ID', var_name = 'group')
df.loc[df['value'] == True][['ID', 'group']]
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`df.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
df['group'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].dot(df.columns[1:])
```

Answer (score 13):

You could use [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to reshape and rename, then boolean filtering on the 'value' column using [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
pd.melt(df,id_vars=['ID'],var_name= 'group').query('value') 

   ID group  value
0   0     A   True
4   1     B   True
8   2     C   True
```

Chaining `.drop('value',axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)` will give your final output:

```
   ID group
0   0     A
1   1     B
2   2     C
```

Answer (score 10):

Yet another way:

```
df.set_index(['ID'])\
  .rename_axis('group', axis=1)\ # getting column name correct
  .stack()\                      # reshaping getting column headers into dataframe rows
  .loc[lambda x: x]\             # filtering for True
  .reset_index()\                # moving ID back into dataframe columns
  .drop(0, axis=1)               # dropping boolean column
```

Output:

```
   ID group
0   0     A
1   1     B
2   2     C
```

Answer (score 9):

More verbose than `melt`, but this drops the invalid columns during the reshaping:

```
(df.set_index('ID')
   .rename_axis(columns='group')
   .replace(False, pd.NA)
   .stack().reset_index().drop(columns=0)
)
```

output:

```
   ID group
0   0     A
1   1     B
2   2     C
```

Answer (score 7):

## `idxmax`

```
s = df.set_index('ID')
s.idxmax(1).where(s.any(1))
```

---

```
ID
0    A
1    B
2    C
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `apply` `lambda`

```
df.set_index('ID').apply(lambda x : x.index[x][0],axis=1)
Out[39]: 
ID
0    A
1    B
2    C
dtype: object
```